# Maths Make It True

Tags: mathematics

Change one of the $+$ signs to an equals sign so that you create an addition problem with a true answer:

> $$\text{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20}$$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the 2- is actually 20...

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14
>  =
>  15+16+17+18+19+20

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

> put '=' in between 14 and 15 ie
>  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14=15+16+17+18+19+20

Easy way to find out N(N+1)/2 =

> (20*21)/2 - N(N+1) /2

Comment: You might want to look at other answers already given before adding one of your own.  How does your answer materially differ from the existing one?

Comment: The other answer didn't say how it was found

Comment: @ULTIMATEGAMER07, regardless, you could have just commented with an explanation.